# The real number x when added to its inverse gives the minimum value of the sum at x equal to

Tags: maxima-minima

The real number x when added to its inverse gives the minimum value of the sum at x equal to what?

According to me it is 2 as $x +(1/x) $ is always equal to greater than 2. But the answer is given as 1.

Comment: Is it any real $x$ or $x>0$? Because $(x-1)^2\geq 0 \Rightarrow x+\frac{1}{x}\geq 2$ if $x>0$!

Comment: Won't the answer be $-\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

*Please read the question carefully.* It says `The real number x when added to its inverse gives the minimum value of the sum at what value of x?`.

Now answer the question. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry , I don't get it

Answer (score 2):

The question asks you at what value of **$x$** you have the minimum sum. Thus the answer is $x=1$ (derive $x+\frac1x$ and look for stationary points), which gives you a sum $s=1+\frac11=1+1=2$

Answer (score 2):

The stationary point for $x + \frac1x$ is $x_0$ s.t. $f^\prime(x_0)=0$. So, $f^\prime(x) = 1-\frac1{x^2} = 0$. Then we have $x_0 = \pm 1$. One point $x_0 = -1$ gives the maximum $(-2)$ for $x < 0$ and the other gives minimum $(2)$ for $x > 0$. See the plot

[image]